# Convert datetime column into day of week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dayofweek

I'm trying to convert a datetime type column into day of week with the code below:

```
date = {'Date': ['2018-10-30', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-30', '2018-10-30']}
df = pd.DataFrame(date)
```

```
df.Date = df.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

```
df.Date.dayofweek()
```

But its runnig this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dayofweek'.
Why is it calling Series object if it's datetime ?

When I slice the column like this:

```
[In] df.Date[0].dayofweek()
[Out] 1
```

I get the expected result.
Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `()` because working with `Series` (`column`) by [`Series.dt.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html):

```
print (df.Date.dt.dayofweek)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Not sure about your pandas version, but for me working [`Timestamp.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.dayofweek.html) also without `()`:

```
print (df.Date.iat[0].dayofweek)
1
```